# DRF validator doesn't return false on uniqueness check

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a user serializer in DRF that looks like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:  # password should exist only if POST
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',
                  'password', 'email', 'username']

        write_only_fields = ['password']
```

And this is what it looks like when I checked the shell.

```
UserSerializer():
    first_name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = CharField(allow_blank=True, max_length=150, required=False)
    password = CharField(max_length=128)
    email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
    username = CharField(help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, validators=[<django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator object>, <UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
```

In my view if I check `is_valid()` on a serializer with data that already exists in the database, the function returns True when it should return False and then a django error is raised:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(myrandomusername) already exists.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `is_valid` is supposed to  raise Validation exception you have a unique constraint specified here `UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())` you can try doing `is_valid(raise_exception=False)`

Comment: @yugandharchaudhari I dont get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `is_valid` will raise exception unless you specify `raise_exception=False` that is expected behaviour to return `serializer.error` from view

Comment: @yugandharchaudhari The exception is raised by Django and not the serializer. This is my issue. The `is_valid()` always True when it shouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializer does not care about whether there is an exception at the lower level, it only cares about the serialization/deserialization. So when you pass a `username` in POST that already exists, the `IntegrityError` is raised on the model layer (after serializer passed the data), not on serializer so it has no idea of it.

Serializer only checked if the deserialization goes on properly i.e. all the data you passed conform to the definition of fields in the serializer. If they are valid, it will pass it on to the next step.

Also, `Serializer.is_valid` only handles `ValidationError`, and keeps a dictionary to refer the errors. For errors, it decides whether to raise a `ValidationError` (from the errors) or not based on `raise_exception`.

---

You should look at the `create` method of the serializer (`ModelSerializer` and subclasses) to handle database level exceptions, as all object creation logic of `ModelSerializer` goes in there. (Also look at `update` method for updating).

DRF provides `ModelSerializer` to ensure the creation and update of model objects from deserialized data, it should be treated as an extension to the definition of basic serializers.

Comment: I figured out the mistake. It doesn't have anything to do with DRF. I have a pre_save function which changes usernames to lowercase so the conflict was from upper/lower case collisions.

Comment: @ninesalt Okay. But that does not answer your question, does it? OTOH, I've tried to clarify your misconception ragarding serializers in general.

Comment: The issue I had does in fact answer my question. I've given you best answer for your effort and help :)

Comment: @ninesalt Thanks for that. But you said in the comment "The exception is raised by Django and not the serializer. This is my issue. The is_valid() always True when it shouldnt" -- which seemed to me that you're concerned about the exception and `is_valid` but now what you're saying that *answered* your question is quite orthogonal to that to be honest. Anyways good luck!

Comment: Yeah I thought `is_valid` was doing something it wasn't supposed to but I was wrong. The problem was with my code.